# How to include jQuery Plugin Mapael into Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

So, I tried following a bit how other questions dealt with the problem of including jQuery Plugins. But let's start with the basics first.

First, I installed the jQuery plugin.

```
npm i jquery
```

Then, I added the typescript definition.

```
npm install -d @types/jquery
```

I included it in my script array.

```
"apps": [{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ],
  ...
}]
```

Then, I tried out if it works.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ww-inventory-map',
  templateUrl: './ww-inventory-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ww-inventory-map.component.scss']
})
export class WwInventoryMapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(window).click(function () {
      alert('ok');
      });
  }


}
```

The response came promptly...

[image]

So far, so good. First work-package is done, time to continue. I installed then the jQuery plugin mapael

```
npm i jquery-mapael
```

angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-mapael/js/jquery.mapael.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"
  ],
  ...
}]
```

After that I tried this. Based on the code example seen on the official page
https://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/#basic-code-example

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    mapael(map: any): JQuery;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ww-inventory-map',
  templateUrl: './ww-inventory-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ww-inventory-map.component.scss']
})
export class WwInventoryMapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(".container").mapael({
      map: {
        name: "world_countries"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

At first things looked fine, no warnings or problems shown, but when I load the page...

[image]

So, I'm at loss how to do this properly. I was hoping that I could fix this somehow. But none of the other few examples have been of much help to me. I apologize, knowing that there have been similar questions, but I can't really get it to work.

**EDIT 1:** The first solution I tried out was from Naga Sai A, but - on my end - it requires some changes, so the compiler won't complain. Thanks, Naga Sai A!

My .ts looks right this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-mapael';
import 'jquery-mapael/js/maps/world_countries.js';

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    mapael(map: any): JQuery;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ww-inventory-map',
  templateUrl: './ww-inventory-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ww-inventory-map.component.scss']
})
export class WwInventoryMapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(".container").mapael({
      map: {
        name: "world_countries"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT 2: Placeholder for Peters solution

The imports are correct, but the component still require the imports. Also, including Raphael.js is NOT required. At least I didn't and the map works splendidly. My setup hasn't changed. Also, I kept my initial way of declaration.

Comment: declare var $:any which might help

Comment: I'll try this out the moment I get home!

Comment: What ever you are trying to do you should avoid using jquery. You should do things in angular way.

Comment: Trust me, I would have loved to avoid using jQuery, but I haven't seen any similar map designs and this particular task requires me to use mapael. @fastAsTortoise

Comment: You can look at amCharts or some other library that doesnt have jquery deps.

Comment: @ak.leimrey, i have updated my anwer with mapael import which seems to be working, hope it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is with your script imports. You are not importing a required dependency for Raphael. Also, you need to import any maps you plan on using. Update your angular-cli.json to the following:

```js
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-mapael/js/jquery.mapael.min.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-mapael/js/maps/world_countries.min.js"
],
```

Note from NPM:

Note on dependencies: jQuery and Raphael (and Mousewheel, if needed) must be loaded before Mapael in order to work properly.

Note on maps: map files must be loaded after Mapael in order to work properly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-mapael#directly-in-your-page

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//jquery declaration
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ww-inventory-map',
  templateUrl: './ww-inventory-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ww-inventory-map.component.scss']
})
export class WwInventoryMapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(".container").mapael({
      map: {
        name: "world_countries"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: While I liked both solutions, I liked this one more, as you went through the trouble to give additional information for the problem. Also, while not specifically needed for this project, it's better for reusable components. Thanks a lot Peter!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of importing jquery, jquery-mapael and js for world countries map

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-mapael';
import 'jquery-mapael/js/maps/world_countries.js';
```

and in ngOnInit

```
 ngOnInit() {
   $(".container").mapael({
      map: {
        name: "world_countries"
      }
    });
  }
```

It works as shown in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Why would you choose using imports for the jQuery libraries instead of defining them in the angular-cli as is pointed out in my answer? I'm also a bit unsure why you didn't at least credit my answer which pointed to the problem 30 minutes before this answer? I would prefer to add the jQuery packages to angular-cli.json especially if this will be used in more than one component as to not duplicate import statements in multiple components.

Comment: yes @Peter, to make reusable component, this ca be imported to one component and reusing that component will do, I was trying to debug the issue - mapel is not a function, after proper import it worked, so i have updated SO. I will test your solution and update my answer

Comment: Sorry for my super delayed response. Train ride took me too long. This solution does work pretty well, but it needs still some changes, so the compiler doesn't complain. I will add it in my question and will also try out Peter's response.

Comment: compiler issue is may be due to declare , i removed it after importing jquery ,jquery-mapael